# Почему не сходится du -h и du -b?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

ПОчему не сходится вывод `du -h` и `du -b`?

```
$ du -h файл
12k
$ du -b файл
8738
```

Comment: Что за тег `du` вы добавили?

Comment: Какая ОС? Как смонтирован раздел? Использовали ли другие ключи помимо -h и -b? С opennet.ru: >ОШИБКИ В РЕАЛИЗАЦИИ
В BSD системах du выдает размеры, которые являются наполовину меньше правильных, для файлов, которые смонтированы по NFS из HP-UX систем. В HP-UX системах du выдает размеры, которые в два раза больше правильных для файлов, которые смонтированы по NFS из BSD систем. Это недостаток систем HP-UX; он также есть и в программе du из HP-UX.

Comment: @zombic, судя по первому тегу - это не *bsd и даже не osx.

Comment: @donRumata скорее всего на тот момент тэгов не было, поэтому и спрашивал.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

читаем `man du` про опцию `-b`:

```
-b, --bytes
       equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1'
```

читаем там же про опцию `--apparent-size`:

```
--apparent-size
       print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size
       is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in  (`sparse')  files,
       internal fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like
```

мой вольный перевод:
выводит «видимые» (apparent) размеры файлов вместо используемого дискового пространства; хотя «видимый» размер обычно меньше, он может быть больше из-за пустого места в «дырявых» (sparse) файлах, внутренней фрагментации, косвенных блоков и т.п.

---

проверяем, что `--apparent-size` даёт в реальности (создаём файл, содержащий 8738 байтов `0x00`):

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file1 bs=1 count=8738
8738+0 records in
8738+0 records out
8738 bytes (8.7 kB) copied, 0.0111545 s, 783 kB/s
$ du -b file1
8738    file1
$ du -h file1
12K file1
$ du -h --apparent-size file1
8.6K    file1
```

а на файле, который вообще пуст (т.н. «дырявый», sparse), получается ещё наглядней:

```
$ truncate -s 8738 file2
$ du -b file2
8738    file2
$ du -h file2
0   file2
$ du -h --apparent-size file2
8.6K    file2
```

---

а откуда, собственно, цифра `12K`? она кратна размеру блока на диске: место под файл отводится блоками. в вашем случае, вероятно, в районе `4K`. уточнить для файловых систем `ext*` можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep -i 'block size'
Block size:               4096
```

где `/dev/sda1` — раздел, на котором находится этот самый рассматриваемый файл.