# Как узнать размер файла на диске

Tags: linux

Как в Linux Mint определить, сколько места занимает разреженный (sparse) файл на диске?
В свойствах показывается только размер файла и не учитывается, что он разреженный.

Comment: imho `du` показывает. Уточните в `man du`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

например, с помощью программы `du`.

создаём «пустой» файл «размером» один мегабайт:

```
$ truncate -s 1M file
```

смотрим, сколько места он занимает на диске:

```
$ du file
0   file
```

p.s. ещё про `du`: [Почему не сходится du -h и du -b?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453058/178576)

Comment: Только truncate лучше куда-то из куска кода вынести.

Comment: @Qwertiy, для чего?

Comment: Чтоб не воспринимался как часть замера размера.

Comment: @alexander barakin 
а как же touch, dd, echo, cat? и стоит рассказать (хоть немного) о разных файловых системах, о цилиндрах и блоках (список можно продолжать).

Comment: @alexander barakin 
о чем я и говорю... простая просьба: не смотрите на все только со своей точки зрения, прислушивайтесь и к остальным